# aarch64 VM; amd64 host; "invalid accelerator kvm"

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtual-machine, qemu

I have an ARM64 machine, which I want to emulate as a VM on my desk for testing.  This will be the first time I'm emulating ARM64 on an AMD64, I'm clueless, and I went fumbling for hints.

I found one example, at: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ARM64/QEMU

The example I'm cargo-culting from that page:
`$ sudo qemu-system-aarch64 -enable-kvm -m 1024 -cpu host -M virt -nographic -pflash /usr/share/AAVMF/AAVMF_CODE.fd -pflash flash1.img -drive if=none,file=jammy-server-cloudimg-arm64.img,id=hd0 -device virtio-blk-device,drive=hd0 -netdev type=tap,id=net0 -device virtio-net-device,netdev=net0,mac=$randmac`

Here's my adjusted version, some notes below:

`# qemu-system-aarch64 -enable-kvm -m 4096 -cpu host -M virt -pflash /usr/share/AAVMF/AAVMF_CODE.fd -pflash flash1.img -drive if=none,file=sal3.internal.raw,id=hd0 -device virtio-blk-device,drive=hd0 -netdev type=tap,id=net0 -device virtio-net-device,netdev=net0,mac=$randmac`

I'm hitting two snags:

1. The example I'm working from assumes a CD as the initial source, but I want to start from a working instance.  The only way I know of to copy the "target" host onto my VM farm is to do a raw copy, then run that in "raw" mode, as shown in the example I'm showing above: "file=sal3.internal.raw"; that's drawing an error:`WARNING: Image format was not specified for 'sal3.internal.raw' and probing guessed raw.
   Automatically detecting the format is dangerous for raw images, write operations on block 0 will be restricted.
   Specify the 'raw' format explicitly to remove the restrictions.`
2. That warning is thrown three times for three items; then the failure:
   `qemu-system-aarch64: invalid accelerator kvm`

I **think** I can work my way around those three warnings, once I have this working, but the hangup is the error saying that kvm isn't correct.  Since I'm doing this in such a copy-and-paste way, and since the example I'm working from **seemed** to think that kvm would handle my aarch64 VM, I don't know how to approach this.

Hints?  Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried to explicit define the format of the image, by using, “format=raw”? Made the QEMU version you are on supports AARCH64 emulation on x86 hardware

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is stated in the linked wiki page:

> accelerated w/ KVM if you have an arm64 host

You can't *virtualize* (i.e. `-enable-kvm`) for a different architecture. (I don't remember if you can do something like virtualize a 32-bit machine with a 64-bit host for the same "family" of architectures, but well, it's not the case here anyway.)

Comment: Oops!  I was misreading the "a" and "b" entries on that page.  You're right, I am emulating aarch64 on x86, not on aarch64.